# Is this finite-difference treatment of the variable-permittivity Poisson equation on a nonuniform grid valid?

Tags: computational-physics, dielectric

Consider the 1D Poisson equation$$\partial_x (\epsilon\partial_x u) = -\rho$$Each site on our 1D grid has an interval to the left $h_l$ and to the right $h_r$. Using a near-central-difference scheme for the first operator, we get
$$\partial_x\left[\epsilon(x) u(x+h_r/2)\right] - \partial_x\left[\epsilon(x) u(x-h_l/2)\right] = -\rho(x)\frac{(h_l+h_r)}{2}$$
For the first term on the LHS, we use a central-difference scheme with interval $h_r$ and the second term, we use a central-difference scheme with interval $h_l$. $$\frac{1}{h_r}\left[\epsilon(x+h_r/2)u(x+h_r) - \epsilon(x-h_r/2)u(x)\right] - \frac{1}{h_l}\left[\epsilon(x+h_l/2)u(x) - \epsilon(x-h_l/2)u(x-h_l)\right] = -\rho(x)\frac{(h_l+h_r)}{2}$$
Rearranging, we get$$u(x) = \left[\rho(x)\frac{(h_l+h_r)}{2} + \frac{u(x+h_r)\epsilon(x+h_r/2)}{h_r} + \frac{u(x-h_l)\epsilon(x-h_l)}{h_l}\right]\times\left[\frac{\epsilon(x+h_l/2)}{h_l} + \frac{\epsilon(x-h_r/2)}{h_r}\right]$$When I write a script to implement this method, it works fine when $\epsilon$ is a constant but fails to converge to the right answer when $\epsilon$ is a step function. When the grid is uniform, it works.

My question: Is there some step I performed above that is not valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly valid to take the finite difference approach for this PDE, even with spatially variable coefficient, $\epsilon$, though you need to be careful with the application of the stencil.

The easiest way to check you are doing it right is to expand the differnetial into two separate terms:
$$\partial_x\left(\epsilon\partial_xu\right)=(\partial_x\epsilon)\times(\partial_xu)+\epsilon\partial_x^2u$$
which should lead to a central scheme of,
\begin{align}
\partial_x\left(\epsilon\partial_xu\right)\approx&\left(\frac{\epsilon(x+h_r)-\epsilon(x-h_l)}{2\Delta x}\right)\times\left(\frac{u(x+h_r)-u(x-h_l)}{2\Delta x}\right)\\ &+\epsilon(x)\frac{u(x+h_r)-2u(x)+u(x-h_l)}{\Delta x^2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
As you can see, if $\epsilon$ is a constant, then the first term drops to zero. When it spatially varies, it is non-zero and must be accounted for in the finite difference scheme.

On a uniform grid, the above can be reduced to something like,
$$\partial_x\left(\epsilon\partial_xu\right)\approx\left[\epsilon_{i+1/2}\left(u_{i+1}-u_i\right)-\epsilon_{i-1/2}\left(u_i-u_{i-1}\right)\right]/\Delta x^2$$
where $\epsilon_{i+1/2}=(\epsilon(x_{i+1})-\epsilon(x_i))/2$. I imagine it may be possible to write something similar for the non-uniform grid (never worked with them & haven't checked this one), but Eq (1) as-is should also work for you directly.

Comment: Thanks. One question: The 2 in the denominator under eps(x+h)-eps(x-h), should that 2 also be in the other denominator under u(x+h) - u(x-h)

Comment: @DJames um yes that 2 should be there.